# arrays shifting to the left by n times

Tags: c++

I tried using loop to shift my array to the left `n` times but each time I enter a number like 2, I will have one number missing and if I entered 3, I will get two numbers missing for example:

> Before: 76 89 100 90 90 100 76 100 90 87

Enter a positive number: 2

> After: 90 76 89 100 90 90 100 76 100`

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    infile>>number[i]>>x;
    cout<<number[i]<<" ";
}

cout<<endl<<"Enter a positive number:";
cin>>n;

for ( i=(size-n);i>=0;i--)
{
    cout<<number[i]<<" ";
}

cout<<endl;
```

Comment: Learn how to use a debugger, then you can step through the code line by line while monitoring all variables and their values.

Comment: print i. => cout << i. You wil find the issue

Comment: what's the result are you excepting?

Comment: can you show your complete main?